# Check if Cloud Firestore query returns something

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say my Cloud Firestore looks like this:

```
users
  ├────random_id_1───{name, email, ...}
  ├────random_id_2───{name, email, ...}
 ...
  └────random_id_n───{name, email, ...}
```

I created a `CollectionReference`:

```
var collectionReference = db.collection("users");
```

Then I created a `Query`:

```
var query = collectionReference.where("name", "==", "John");
```

My goal is to **check if the query finds something or not**, I just want this answer (so I can use it in an if-else statement).

If possible, I **don't** want to use this approach, even that it works:

```
query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log('no documents found');
    } else {
        // do something with the data
    }
});
```

It's too much code to give a simple boolean about the query.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you've shared is the idiomatic approach to check for the existence of a document, so there aren't any better options.

The only thing I can think of is if you're on an environment that supports `async`/`await` in which case you can do this:

```
let querySnapshot = await query.get();
if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log('no documents found');
} else {
    // do something with the data
}
```

You could probably even condense the first two lines into:

```
if ((await query.get()).empty) {
  ...
```

I don't like this last chance all that much though. Hiding complexity like this always ends up being a leaky abstraction at some point.

Comment: Well, I'll stick to the idiomatic approach then... PS: I knew you would be the one to answer hehe :)